# iOS7 Mobile Safari offline data storage options

Tags: web-applications, indexeddb, web-sql, ios7, offline-storage

I'm looking to build offline-capable web apps in the next few months that require persistant client-side storage ideally larger than localStore and was curious does anyone know the status of IndexedDB in iOS 7 beta? I'm guessing it's still not available but am not seeing it tested on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb%20%22caniuse) yet.

Web-Sql was deprecated years ago so I'm reluctant to continue relying on it but it still appears to be available on iOS 7 beta according to caniuse so I suppose an alternative would be to stick with websql for now or use [a polyfill](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/).

I'm just trying to avoid relying too heavily on web-sql if it's not going to be around much longer or most other platforms have moved on to IndexedDB in the meantime.

Comment: For questions about iOS7, which is still under NDA, please visit the Apple Developer forums.

Comment: For whats it's worth. iOS 8 now supports indexDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice you to use the polyfill for now. this way your code will be indexeddb API ready. When the indexedDB API then arrives it's only a matter of disabling the polyfill (and that will even happen automatically)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628980/wrapper-to-support-both-websql-and-indexeddb/18723520#18723520

Comment: That makes perfect sense - and thank you for pointing me in the direction of a polyfill as well!