# Wrapper to support both webSql and indexedDB?

Tags: html, indexeddb, web-sql, jaydata, offline-browsing

My application should support offline mode on the following browsers:

- IE
- Chrome
- Firefox
- Safari (supports WebSQL only)

and also application using KendoUI for UI. I have looked at **JayData** which looks good fit for my requirement but I heard JayData wouldn't support some good features like Transactions and so. please share your feedback on Jaydata. also suggest best wrapper to support both webSql and indexedDB?

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/using-indexeddb-api-today-the-indexeddb-polyfills/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JayData Pro does support transactions, it's free for non-commercial use and payware for commercial use.

Comment: Yes, as Gabor says it does support transactions. More info here- IndexedDB Provider Pro with transactions - http://jaystack.com/blog/jaydata-indexedDB-pro-provider 
WebSQL Provider Pro with transactions - http://jaystack.com/blog/jaydata-SQlite-pro-provider  - Disclaimer: I'm member of the dev team, feel free to ask for more technical docs

Answer (score 2):

facebook has an [indexeddb polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/IndexedDB-polyfill), although there is a [bug with indices](https://github.com/facebook/IndexedDB-polyfill/pull/5).

my [fork](https://github.com/firien/IndexedDB-polyfill/tree/index_fix) (branch:index_fix) has a fix and a pull request is pending. note: the minified js was not updated, use [un-minified version](https://github.com/firien/IndexedDB-polyfill/blob/index_fix/indexedDB.polyfill.js)

I have two indexedDB apps and i dropped [indexedDB.polyfill.js](https://github.com/firien/IndexedDB-polyfill/blob/index_fix/indexedDB.polyfill.js) in there and everything worked perfectly on safari (OSX and iOS)

Answer (score 1):

Suitable library depends on use case.

Try my open source library,  ydn-db,http://dev.yathit.com/api-reference/ydn-db/storage.html lt supports all of those features.

I will use jaydata for backend sync with odata service. Otherwise, too heavy. Ydn-db itself is heavy. There are many thin wrapper out there. Use facebook indexeddb polyfill for websql.